# When Alfred cries in front of Gordon at Bruce Wayne's funeral, was he faking it?

Tags: the-dark-knight-rises

In the Dark Knight Rises during the ending scene, we see that Alferd is crying in front of Gordon and Blake at Bruce Wayne's Funeral. After sometime we see that Alferd sees Brue Wayne and Selina Kayle at a place (as he had imagined once).
So I want to know that when did Alfred come to know about the reality of Bruce's death?

Had he known it all before because if that is the case then his crying at funeral was just a mask to fool Gordon and Blake.

Or is it that at that time he genuinely believed that Bruce is dead and only later he came to know that he is alive and where to find him?

Comment: The latter explanation (he was not faking it) really makes the only sense in the context of the movie. But I have a strong feeling this was asked before in some way, will dig it up when I have the time...Ah, found it.

Comment: And by the way, *"Or is it that at that time he genuinely believed that Bruce is dead and only later he came to know that he is alive and where to find him?"* - He did never look for *Bruce* to find him, it was *Bruce* who found *Alfred*, since he knew he would sit in that cafe.

Comment: While rethinking it, it may not be a perfect duplicate, since *Alfred* might not have been in on *Bruce*'s plan but could still have guessed that he is alive. Yet the answers from the duplicate still apply to this question.